# JFileChooser - setting a fixed file name

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

I am making an application that works similar to a text editor with code highlighting.

When I try to save some text, I want a fixed file name to appear on the JFileChooser which will not change while navigating through directories.

The reason I am doing that is because the user is going to save .java files. That file should have the name of the given class. Having the user type the name can only cause mistakes which will slow compiling and doesn't make sense.

This is what I have atm:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int userSelection = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String name = f.getAbsolutePath();
        File newFile = new File(name);//the text is written on this file.
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, since it's been a while since I used Swing, but you'll get only DirectoryPaths because of the Option "DIRECTORIES_ONLY", so you can automatically append the Filename programmatically and you're done. Or do you want the user to explicitly see what it's going to be but not be able to change it?

Comment: Then can't you let the user select a directory (which you appear to be doing already), then store the file in that directory with the name you prefer?

Comment: Btw, if you are saving java file, you may also need to take the package into account.

Comment: Good point, @Gauillaume, I second that!

Comment: Well on File newFile = new File(name); I can add the name I want.Although in order to click save on the fileChooser,I need to have a name typed. Thats whats causing trouble. I want either not to have to type a name, or have that name fixed. @GuillaumePolet thanks I will look at that later. Files with packages are indeed causing some trouble atm.

Comment: Ok..setting fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY) and         fc.setSelectedFile(new File("file_name")), solved the problem. Default name doesnt change while moving through directories and when I get where I want I can click save.

Comment: Yes, but this does not prevent the user from modifying the file name. Personnally, I would simply ask the user to choose a src directory for the java files with a DIRECTORY_ONLY filechooser and then I would automatically create the appropriate package structure and save with the appropriate file name. This would prevent any future problem. If you want the name of the java file to appear, you can use the FileChoose title or use an "accessory" JLabel component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know exactly, if that helps you. But I've had a similar problem and solved it like this:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int userSelection = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String name = f.getAbsolutePath();
        File newFile = new File(name + "\\" + yourfilenamehere);//the text is written on this file.
    }
```

I fear, that it sounds too easy... Just repace "yourfilenamehere" with the desired (fixed) filename.

Comment: I think the solution I needed was use the directory only. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: The "problem" with this solution is that the user doesn't see the filename. In my case, it'd be better if it shows the name although it should be read-only.